# How to use generic type constraint to enforce Add method existence

Tags: c#, generics

I have this code that uses the generic code:

```
    public static async Task<List<string>> GetDomainsAsync(IMemoryCache _cache)
    {
        return await ContextCache.CacheTryGetValueSet<List<String>>("SP_GET_DOMAINS", _cache);
    }

    public static async Task<Dictionary<String, String>> GetSettingsAsync(IMemoryCache _cache)
    {
        return await ContextCache.CacheTryGetValueSet<Dictionary<String, String>>("SP_GET_SETTINGS", _cache);
    }
```

And this is the generic method:

```
private static async Task<T> CacheTryGetValueSet<T>(String SPName, IMemoryCache _cache) where T : new()
{
          dynamic data = new T();


        ....

         while (reader.Read())
                                        {
                                            if (reader.FieldCount == 1)
                                            {
                                                data.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                                            }
                                            else if (reader.FieldCount == 2)
                                            {
                                                data.Add(reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
                                            }
                                        }
        ....

        return data;

        }
```

How can I make sure that `T` in-fact has an `Add` method?
What generic type constraint can be added to make sure that only IEnumerable can be passed?

Comment: Do you want to ensure that both the Add signatures you use are implemented?

Comment: `IEnumerable` doesn't have an `Add` method, it's simply not in its contract. Perhaps clarify that what you *really* mean is you are looking for Dictionary semantics via that `Add` method. The answer is going to be to constrain your type parameter to `IDictionary<T, U>` (or one of its descendants) which is the only way you'll get the two parameter `Add` method. And why on earth are you using `dynamic`? You know the type of `data`, it's `T`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you have a generic method that contains `if (typeof(T))`, you are probably doing it wrong. The whole point of generics is that they operate exactly the same on a variety of types. If the types are too different (e.g. a dictionary that needs two fields versus a list that needs one) you end up writing non-generic code in a generic method, which just confuses things.

In this case you should probably have two methods, one that accepts one type parameter (which returns an `IEnumerable<TItem>`, which the caller can easily convert to a List or use in LINQ statements) and one that accepts two type parameters (which returns an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>`, which the caller can convert to a dictionary or use in LINQ).

In addition, you probably should use `yield return` as rows become available so you don't have to read the entire rowset before the caller can start processing data. This will smooth out your performance, and neatly avoids the issue of figuring out whether there is an `Add()` method-- you don't need it.

Here is an example of a way you could rewrite your method to address these issues. It's a little tricky because you have to use a nested function to use `yield return` in an `async Task`:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TItem>> CacheTryGetValueSet<TItem>(string storedProcedureName, IMemoryCache cache)
{
    IEnumerable<TItem> Enumerate(SqlDataReader source)
    {
        while (source.Read())
        {
            yield return source.GetFieldValue<TItem>(0);
        }
    }

    var reader = await OpenReaderAsync(storedProcedureName);
    if (reader.FieldCount != 1) throw new ArgumentException("That type of cache doesn't return a single column.");
    return Enumerate(reader);
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>> CacheTryGetValueSet<TKey,TValue>(string storedProcedureName, IMemoryCache cache)
{
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>> Enumerate(SqlDataReader source)
    {
        while (source.Read())
        {
            yield return new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>
            (
                source.GetFieldValue<TKey>(0),
                source.GetFieldValue<TValue>(1)
            );
        }
    }

    var reader = await OpenReaderAsync(storedProcedureName);
    if (reader.FieldCount != 2) throw new ArgumentException("That type of cache doesn't return two columns!");
    return Enumerate(reader);
}
```

Now the caller can call it this way:

```
public static async Task<List<string>> GetDomainsAsync(IMemoryCache _cache)
{
    return await ContextCache.CacheTryGetValueSet<string>("SP_GET_DOMAINS", _cache).ToList();
}

public static async Task<Dictionary<String, String>> GetSettingsAsync(IMemoryCache _cache)
{
    return await ContextCache.CacheTryGetValueSet<String, String>("SP_GET_SETTINGS", _cache).ToDictionary();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `ICollection<string>` interface be the generic type constraint `where T :  ICollection<string>, new()`.

Comment: I have tried this, this is the error that I get: The type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'ContextCache.CacheTryGetValueSet<T>(string, IMemoryCache)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>'.

Comment: `where T : ICollection<string>, new()` in this case. No need for a recursive generic definition.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior ICollection<string> is not a IDictionary<String,String>

Comment: @realPro: You're going to need to elaborate on that. Nothing you've said so far had anything to do with `IDictionary<>`. The exception you reported is talking about a `List<string>`. I asked in a comment on your question about the second `Add` signature, but you haven't answered the question. If you want your method to accept any generic List-like _or_ Dictionary-like structure, you'll need two separate method signatures, and there's still a possibility things will break at run-time if FieldCount doesn't match the generic type you provided.

Comment: @realPro instead of insulting someone trying to help you, maybe take a step back and realize that you in fact have said nothing about a dictionary in your question (evidenced by the fact all responses thus far have suggested IList/ICollection), nor did you answer the comment on the OP asking for clarification

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to guarantee that there's a specific method on a generic at compile time, but you can enforce that the generic type implement an interface such as IList which has an Add method.

I.E.

```
public T Foo<T>() where T : IList, new()
{
  var list = new T();
  list.Add(...);
  return list;
}
```

Comment: This does not compile, and also Dictionary is not a List

Comment: It does compile other than the ellipsis, which was just meant as a placeholder. My answer was more targeted at your more general question of adding method existence constraints, not your specific code. As you point out, List and Dictionary don't share even a common signature for Add(), so you probably consider some plain old overloads.